# how to stretch a div to fit into the body height

Tags: html, css

If you visit this website of mine : http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe2/index.php?mid=board_WfBV76

you notice that there is background image of the body shown to the background due to the empty space.

is there a way i can make .content vertically taller so that the #footer reach the very bottom of the page other than using min-height or any height value at all?

I just want to make it look full.

any ideas?

Comment: Instead of linking to a live site always consider to attach a simple explanatory fiddle please. that will make us help you faster.

Comment: give body's height:100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put style on **div#body**

```
<div id="body" class="sub_content_bg no_slider">
```

CSS /style:

```
height: 100%
```

It will result to footer send to the bottom of the page.

Additional answer, add to (div id="body") :

```
display: inline;
```

Comment: thanks. one quick question before i accept your answer though. i gave the body 100%, and in order to fill the gap between the footer and the content, i gave .body_container #fff and now it covers the entire page including the footer (i cannot see footer) any solution to this?

Comment: I cannot give #body #fff, because that will cover my submenu.

Comment: i will check to html codes in your link, please wait.

Comment: try to add position: relative; to element id="footer"

OR try to move the <div id="footer">...</div> in <div id="body">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `<body style="height=90%">` in whatever you are creating. You can assign height of any division or content by specifying height in percents